# Does WordPress consider a post name unique if that same post name is in multiple Post Types?

Tags: custom-post-types, permalinks

I have a situation that I thought WordPress handled, but I seem to have a misunderstanding about how it works.

Posts of the same name, under different custom post types, are auto incrementing.

I thought wordpress would handle /post-type-red/about and /post-type-blue/about as unique, but in with the post that I enter later, WP auto increments that post number.

Is my understanding wrong here of how this should work?

Answer (score 1):

You could potentially have all permalinks use only the post_name (as many do, for SEO purposes), so therefore it must be unique across all types.

Comment: Thanks Biranit. I currently have /%postname%/ set for permalinks. I think that WordPress, needs to have the actual "slug" be a unique value, regardless of the preceeding structure. I never knew that to be the case until this project I'm working on.

A Child and parent page structure will give me what I want, but I need to have custom  post types for this to work as expected.

Comment: This is correct, it not about seo, it's about how WordPress stores the data in the database. You basically cannot have duplicate slugs for posts, categories or anything, there are trac tickets to fix this because at one point way back it was possible.